# Share internet connection from Ubuntu VM running on Windows Hyper-v to another Ubuntu VM running on a different hyper-v server

Tags: networking, windows, network-bridge, sharing, hyper-v

I'd like to know how to share internet connection from an Ubuntu 22.04 VM (server) running inside Hyper-v Windows 10 machine to another Ubuntu VM 22.04 (client) running in hyper-v a different windows machine.

My server Ubuntu machine receives internet from Windows machine where it runs, I cannot however share connection directly from this Windows machine since I don't have admin permissions.

Both physical machines running Windows with their respective Ubuntu VMs are connected to the same router and local network. I'd like to know if there's a straightforward way to share connection between Ubuntu server to Ubuntu client without having to mess with Hyper-v switches on Windows server machine.

The aim is to be able to work on Ubuntu VM (client) that has much more powerful hardware and just use the Ubuntu (server) as a bridge sharing all the traffic.